# How to make Ubuntu read aloud every key I type?

Tags: text-to-speech, voice-recognition

I want to configure Ubuntu to read aloud the keys and words I type.

For example, if I type <kbd>b</kbd> it should say "b" in the background. While I'm using other applications, the system should say each word aloud as I click it.

How do I configure this?

Answer (score 2):

In "Settings", "Accessibility", enable "Screen Reader" under the "Seeing" section.